# Make a ControllerAdvice error handler that ignores Spring Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot application. Spring automatically handles some input errors from clients. For example, if I have a controller like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/order")
public class OrderController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Order> getOrder(
            @PathVariable("id") int id) {

        Order order = this.orderService.get(id);

        if (order != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(order, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

}
```

If the `id` input isn't included in the request from a client, or Spring can't make it an int, Spring will automatically return a proper 400 status code.

Now, let's say I want to log any failures in this method that happen due to errors in business logic. I create a Controller Advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerExceptionHandler.class);

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler({ RuntimeException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleError(final RuntimeException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Got internal server error.", ex);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

The problem is that now if the client sends bad input, my controller advice method is running and returning a 500, not a 400. **How do I create an exception handler that ignores exceptions thrown by Spring?**

I don't want to be specific in the errors I catch, because I want to catch and log anything and everything. If a library throws an Exception I didn't even know it could throw, I want to log that. If I introduced a potential NullPointerException, I want to log that. However, I want to keep Spring's helpful default handling of its Exceptions.

I could rethrow the Exception within the handler method, and Spring would handle it if it is a Spring Exception. But then I end up logging bad client input, which I don't want. Especially in a log that says "Got internal server error", which is misleading.

Most of the questions already on here are about their ControllerAdvice implementations not working. This one works, but I want to limit it to handling Exceptions thrown by the application code, not the framework.

Comment: If you just want to log errors, why not use a filter instead and log errors inside the finally block?

Comment: @SarahCassar This example is very simplified. In the real application, the ControllerAdvice class already has several methods handling more specific exceptions. I would like to keep all the error handling in one class if possible. If there are no other options though, I will try that. Hopefully it doesn't also end up logging Exceptions thrown by Spring though.

Comment: In what order are exceptions handled? This can happen if you catch RuntimeException before there was a chance to resolve other exceptions. Try reducing the order of this controller advice, remove ResponseStatus annotation as well. If still not working, please help with a reproducible example.

Comment: As I stated in my answer bellow try adding extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler to your 
 ControllerExceptionHandler ;-)

Comment: Hi @SarahCassar. I ended up going with your suggestion. If you would like, please create an answer so that I can accept it. I realized that the application already had a filter that was logging requests and their responses. Actually, this filter was not logging requests that failed because of an uncaught exception, because it did not have a try/catch. So it made the most sense to fix that and log the Exception right there as well.

Comment: I think it was the right decision in your context!

Answer (score 3):

I think that a controller advice implementation from https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-exception-handling/#controlleradvice
might solve your problem.

```
ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
  @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllUncaughtException(
      RuntimeException exception, 
      WebRequest request
  ){
      //Log the exception and handle it here
  }

  @Override
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(
      Exception ex,
      Object body,
      HttpHeaders headers,
      HttpStatus status,
      WebRequest request) {
      //Log the exception and handle it here
  }

}
```

The base class **ResponseEntityExceptionHandler** contains exception handlers for standard Spring exceptions. I read that spring handles most specific exceptions from controller advises first. In case of a spring error default code will handle it. In case of a runtime exception, your handler will be executed.

Comment: Hello. This answer looks great! I ended up going with a suggestion in the comments of the question, because some existing code in the project happened to suit that approach. But if not for that, I'm sure this would have been a great solution. Thank you for taking the time to look into my question.